# What exactly is "Park Balance Bonus"?

Tags: planet-coaster

Among the stats which contribute to your overall Park Rating is a point "Park Balance Bonus". How exactly is that stat calculated and what can I do to improve it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Park Balance Bonus" is the ratio of the number of rides to the number of scenery items in your park.  This balance bonus is a factor in how many guests appear at your park.

The "Park Balance Bonus" appears to be calculated by a one to one ratio based on dollars spent in the appropriate category. To achieve the perfect ratio (1.00), For every dollar spent on rides, one dollar should be spent on scenery. This ratio is difficult to achieve as this is not typically the most effective strategy to create profit.

**Source:** ~/steam/steamapps/common/planet coaster/win64/ovldata/content0/main.ovl

**Additional Reference:** http://www.planetcoasterstrategy.com/planet-coaster-park-management-screen/

Comment: @Philipp - Update - I can't find any online sources so I'm going to go try to review the code on this tonight.  From sandbox testing, I believe that this is a one to one ratio (dollar spent per dollar spent). The mechanic is meant to give additional incentives to the player to not just build rides.  If you're park is just ride objects only, you're ratio will be poor. Same with just scenery items.

Comment: I've taken a look at the main.ovl file and it appears that the ratio is one to one. Meaning, in order to achieve the best balance, for every dollar spent on a ride, a dollar should be spent on scenery.  This is a really difficult ratio to achieve in game, which is why it's typically around 50 to 60.

Feel free to review, the default directory is ~/steam/steamapps/common/planet coaster/win64/ovldata/content0/main.ovl

Comment: Sorry for the delay ... work. lol Edited and updated.

Comment: "This is a really difficult ratio to achieve in game [...]" not really, if you spam (I mean actually need ;) ) quite a few golden treasure chests. Or does that count differently?